# Why does it exist?

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis

I can show that $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{a} (\cos(tu)-e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}})e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$ converges to 0 but I am not sure why this implies the convergence of $$\lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{b} (\cos(tu)-e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}})e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$$ and moreover it is also converges to zero.

Comment: Do you really mean $b\to \color{red}-\infty$?

Comment: Yes I mean b tend to negative infinity.

Comment: What happens if you integrate between "a" and "a" ?

Comment: Year I had thought about that $$\lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{b} ... du = \lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} \int_{b}^{b} ... du $$ which is alway zero but my teacher told me that this is not the right reason. He does not tell what it is but just said what I told you that the first integration I mentioned which converges will be the reason why the integration I asked converges and converges to zero. But I am very confused how this reason works ?????

Comment: Any suggestion please ?